# Accurate splitting value of graduated symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

Everytime I use graduated symbology in QGIS I am in doubt how the intervals precisely are split.

Doing some manual testing with integer attributes I can see that the "real" intervals are like the ones I have manually edited in the legend column.

Is there any way to automatically make QGIS more "explicit" in the legend?

Or at least in the Values column write 2,00<-5,00 so I know that 2 is not included in that interval.

[image: The splitting values between intervals in graduated symbology]

Comment: It is manual but you can click in the Legend column for any row and change what is displayed there.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the standard settings could be improved. However, you can easily change these within "legend format":

[image]

`%1` describes the first value (lower) and `%2` the second (upper) one. Everything is else is up to you, how you want to display your legend. E.g. `from >%1 to <=%2`

Comment: A usable workaround - as long as I can remember that QGIS actually shows %1<-%2 :-)

Comment: If that is a workaround for you, what would not?